# Junit in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, junit

I'm having issues getting the "PASS" messages to appear when running the junit. Nothing happens at all when I hit run. The system.out won't output either. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

FullTestSuite.java

```
import android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import cen4910.ucf.edu.aaa_android_auto.pojo.Driver;

public class FullTestSuite {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        DriverTest.test();
        /*
        Driver testDriver = new Driver("password", "john", "smith", "test@gmail.com");
        AssertNotNull(testDriver);
    }
}
```

DriverTest.java

```
import pojo.Driver;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class DriverTest {
    public static void test() {
        Driver testDriver = new Driver("password", "john", "smith", "test@gmail.com");
        assertNotNull(testDriver);
        if (testDriver == null) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Failure!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you have a `main` method? Create your test classes under `src/main/test` and put `@Test` in your test methods instead.

Comment: You don't need `System.out.println`. The tests will tell you themselves if they pass or fail. Also, "Failure" won't even be printed if the assert is not met.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't uses Android-Studio, but I don't see a JUnit Testcase in your code.

try to annotate your Testcase with `@Test`. A main-method is not needed to start JUnit tests.

Maybe you should read a JUnit tutorial to unterstand the basics on how to run a JUnit test in your favorite IDE.

```
import pojo.Driver;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DriverTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Driver testDriver = new Driver("password", "john", "smith", "test@gmail.com");
        assertNotNull(testDriver);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the if/else clause is not needed. I mean, `assertNotNull` call will determine if test pass or not.

Comment: not can, will.  The test will fail right then and there and not even reach the if block if it fails.

Comment: I understand that the junit should tell if it will pass/fail and the system.out is unnecessary, but I'm not getting any output at all. Pass/Fail never appears like it would in eclipse. I'm not used to doing it android studio. I added @Test , but pass/fail still won't appear when I run FullTestSuite.java.